# Поиск строки в подстроке PHP

Tags: php

Есть код

```
$keys[] = "машина";
$keys[] = "квартира";
$keys[] = "дача";
$keys[] = "жена";

$searchStr[] = "шин";
$searchStr[] = "дач";
$searchStr[] = "жен";

for ($i = 0; $i<count($keys); $i++) {
    $tmp = "";
    for ($j = 0; $j<count($searchStr); $j++) {
        //$tmp = "";
        echo $j.$searchStr[j]; // ВОТ ЭТА СТРОКА!!!!!
        $pos = strpos($keys[$i], $searchStr[j]);

        echo "/".$keys[$i].".".$searchStr[j]."/";
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $tmp = $searchStr[j]."-"; break(1);
            //echo $keys[$i].";<b><font color=red>".$searchStr[j]."</font></b><br>";
        } else {
            $tmp = $searchStr[j]."+";
        }
        //echo "!";
    }
    echo $keys[$i].";<b><font color=red>".$tmp."</font></b><br>";
}
```

там есть строка, помеченная комментарием "ВОТ ЭТА СТРОКА!!" :)
почему там не выводится переменная $searchStr[j] ? уже час бьюсь, не могу понять! помогитеее..

Comment: Напишите какой результат вы хотите получить. Не совсем понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не стоит знак $ перед переменной.
Из-за этого в массиве ищется элемент со строковым ключом "j".
Такого ключа в массиве нет, поэтому возвращается пустое значение.

Замените все

```
$searchStr[j]
```

На

```
$searchStr[$j]
```